# Por qué Router Outlet me duplica los componentes?

Tags: angular

soy iniciante en Angular y en mi componente principal tengo esto

```
 <app-header>
  </app-header>



    <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
        <h3><a [routerLink]="['/VerLibros']">ver libros</a></h3>

        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
```

```
En mi localhost veo los componentes duplicado, de esta forma:
```

HEADER - VER LIBROS - HEADER - VER LIBROS - FOOTER - FOOTER

alguno sabe como hacer para que eso no pase?

Comment: Cuantos `router-outlet` tienes en tu aplicación? Angular permite la ejecución de multiples routers, esto provoca componentes duplicados. En general, solo pon uno dentro de `app.component.html` y con eso bastará. Así lo tienes?

Answer (score 0):

Y si lo colocas dentro de un section?? Ejemplo:

```
<app-header>    </app-header>

<div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
<section id="content">

<h3><a [routerLink]="['/VerLibros']">ver libros</a></h3>

 <router-outlet></router-outlet>

 </section>

 </div>


 <app-footer></app-footer>
```